# JOIN unrelated tables by t1.date (between t2.startdate and t2.enddate)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssas

A SQL question, probably not the most difficult.

I'm making a view from a bunch of related table join on ID's -> easy. Now there is one table that hasn't got a key relationship with all the others. (BatchDates)

```
`ALTER VIEW [ECSUB].[FCT_Ext_Collection]
AS
SELECT     sh.id AS idSubmissionHistory, dh.id, dd.id AS Description, sch.id AS idScoringHistory, sh.CreationDate, sh.UpdateDate, bd.id AS BatchDateID
FROM         ECSUB.SubmissionHistory AS sh INNER JOIN EC.DocumentHistory AS dh ON sh.id = dh.idSubmissionHistory 
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN ECSM.ScoringHistory AS sch ON sh.idScoringHistory = sch.id 
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN EC.DocumentDescriptions AS dd ON dd.id = dh.Description 
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN ECSUB.AddressBilling AS ab ON sh.id = ab.id 
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN ECSUB.AddressPremise AS ap ON sh.id = ap.id 
                      CROSS JOIN EC.BatchDates AS bd --ON sh.documentdate between .......

GO`
```

Well, my main table 'documentHistory' contains a document date, I have to define in which batch this falls.
Each batch has an ID and startdate. A batch is always one month long.

This will make it much more easy to understand, the data from the BatchDates table:

```
id  month   startdate
1   2010-12-01 00:00:00.000 2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
1   2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
1   2011-02-01 00:00:00.000 2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
2   2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 2011-03-01 00:00:00.000
2   2011-04-01 00:00:00.000 2011-03-01 00:00:00.000
2   2011-05-01 00:00:00.000 2011-03-01 00:00:00.000
3   2011-06-01 00:00:00.000 2011-06-01 00:00:00.000
3   2011-07-01 00:00:00.000 2011-06-01 00:00:00.000
3   2011-08-01 00:00:00.000 2011-06-01 00:00:00.000
4   2011-09-01 00:00:00.000 2011-09-01 00:00:00.000
4   2011-10-01 00:00:00.000 2011-09-01 00:00:00.000
4   2011-11-01 00:00:00.000 2011-09-01 00:00:00.000
5   2011-12-01 00:00:00.000 2011-12-01 00:00:00.000
5   2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 2011-12-01 00:00:00.000
5   2012-02-01 00:00:00.000 2011-12-01 00:00:00.000
6   2012-03-01 00:00:00.000 2012-03-01 00:00:00.000
6   2012-04-01 00:00:00.000 2012-03-01 00:00:00.000
6   2012-05-01 00:00:00.000 2012-03-01 00:00:00.000
7   2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 2012-06-01 00:00:00.000
7   2012-07-01 00:00:00.000 2012-06-01 00:00:00.000
7   2012-08-01 00:00:00.000 2012-06-01 00:00:00.000
8   2012-09-01 00:00:00.000 2012-09-01 00:00:00.000
8   2012-10-01 00:00:00.000 2012-09-01 00:00:00.000
8   2012-11-01 00:00:00.000 2012-09-01 00:00:00.000
9   2012-12-01 00:00:00.000 2012-12-01 00:00:00.000
9   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2012-12-01 00:00:00.000
9   2013-02-01 00:00:00.000 2012-12-01 00:00:00.000
10  2013-03-01 00:00:00.000 2013-03-01 00:00:00.000
10  2013-04-01 00:00:00.000 2013-03-01 00:00:00.000
10  2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 2013-03-01 00:00:00.000
etc...........
```

So I need to fetch the batchID based on the documentdate, therefore we use the *currentMonth* of the column startdate.

Thus: ...JOIN BatchDates where documentDate is in startDate.month  (there is no between here)

I don't even know if I need a join, cross join, union, etc...

Thanks in advance!
L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
join BatchDates 
on datepart(yyyy,[document date]) = datepart(yyyy,[startDate])
and datepart(mm,[document date]) = datepart(mm,[startDate])
```